# ClickOnce Deployed to Multiple Network Shares

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

We have several offices around the US and one in India.  Our IT department setup a system where we copy files and directories to a specific shared folder on a local server and it will be distributed to another office.  In other words, we have a folder on a local server called "To India".  When I copy a folder there it will be sent to India using UDP (or whatever speedier than Windows file transfer method) to a folder called "From East Coast US Office".

I have a ClickOnce application that I deploy to a local network share that our developers use.  Our QA team in India also wants to be able to use this application.  I set up a job that copies the contents of the deployment folder to the shared network folder every hour.  All this works flawlessly.

In India they get the ApplicationFiles directory, setup program, and "application" file just as it appears where I deploy it locally.  They run the setup program, but instead of downloading the application files from their local machine it starts downloading the application files (dlls, etc) from where application was originally deployed.

This is a big deal for us because some of the 3rd party DLLs are rather large (50+ mb) and the transfers are often dropped causing the install to fail.  Is there a way to deploy to multiple locations or edit some file through a script so that when the India QA team installs from their local server the files are pulled from there (and updates look to that folder too)?

I've looked at several files in notepad.  It seems like I may have to edit the ".application" file somehow.  Any ideas?

PS: I know this sounds like a ServerFault or SuperUser question, but I figure that since it is specifically related to the functionality of ClickOnce it is probably better addressed here first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is as designed.  Click-once applications are designed to be deployed to one location.  You can specify an update location, but these locations become static once the application is deployed.

The best bet for anyone looking to do this would be some sort of content hosting solution ala Akamai.  I tried to come up with a solution similar to that but my IT/Network Admin skills are lacking.